# Getting an XML sitemap with custom namespace to output its data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, firefox

Here's my sample XML sitemap:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:example="http://www.example.com/schemas/example_schema">
  <url>
    <loc>
      http://www.example.com/items/sample-item-1/
    </loc>
    <example:example>
      <example:title>Sample Item 1</example:title>
      <example:tag>tag-1</example:tag>
      <example:tag>tag-2</example:tag>
      <example:tag>tag-3</example:tag>
    </example:example>
  </url>
  <url>...</url>
  <url>...</url>
  ...
</urlset>
```

By doing this JScript:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        complete: function ( xhr, status ) {
            testFunc( xhr.responseXML );
        }
    } );
} );

function testFunc( xml ) {
    var urls = $( xml ).find( 'url' );
    urls.each( function () {
        var elem = $( this );
        console.debug( elem.find( 'title' ).text() );

        var tags = elem.find( 'tag' );
        tags.each( function () {
            var tag = $( this );
            console.debug( '  - ' + tag.text() );
        } );
    } );
}
```

Here's the output on Chrome:

```
Sample Item 1
  - tag-1
  - tag-2
  - tag-3
Sample Item 2
  - tag-1
...
```

But the output on Firefox 42 is just:

```
[blank]...
not well-formed
```

And on IE11 is just a sequence of blank lines.

When I do this:

```
            // testFunc( xhr.responseXML );
            testFunc( xhr.responseText );
        }
    } );
} );
function testFunc ( text ) {
    var urls = $( text ).find( 'url' );
    urls.each( function () {
        var elem = $( this );
        console.debug( elem.find( 'loc' ).text() );
    } );
}
```

Firefox and IE are outputting:

```
http://www.example.com/items/sample-item-1/
http://www.example.com/items/sample-item-2/
...
```

But when I change this line:

```
// console.debug( elem.find( 'loc' ).text() );
```

with:

```
console.debug( elem.find( 'title' ).text() );
```

All of the browsers will just output a sequence of blanks instead of titles.

I've tried jFeed and checked Google Feed API but they seems useless for the unique tags of the custom namespace.

What I want is to achieve my first JScript but with an argument of `xhr.responseText` instead of `xhr.responseXML` to make it cross-browser compatibility. *(*Anyone know how can I solve this or any alternative? Thanks..)*

Comment: @CBroe No, they're not.. I already got the answer.